# What is the right place to initialize third-party API in Django project for later Celery use

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a twitter API used in my Django project.

Right now I keep initialization in my `settings.py` and in `tasks.py` I just import API from `django.conf.settings`. I am not sure if it's a good practice as I've never seen it. Do I need to create API instance somewhere in `celery.py` or even in the task function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Celery better in the task function

Comment: This will create api instance for each call of a task. Is it okay?

Comment: You don't know which server and at what time to perform the task. It is better to be initialized all in the task. And for this reason, the problem is always better to specify simple objects as parameters. For example post.id better instead of the instance, and select a an instance in the task